# printf displays different values for the same variable

Tags: java, numbers

I found this code online and when compiled it prints 5 and 10:

```
int numbеr = 5;
int number = 10;
System.out.printf("Number one is %d and number two is %d.", numbеr, number);
```

**How can this work ?!**

Comment: My compiler issued following warning: *Don't ever write such code. Good friends may turn away from you*.

Comment: I can't reproduce this - am I missing something?

Comment: Try to copy/paste his code exactly, mot enter it manually.

Comment: You can tell that the two definitions are not for the same name because redefining a variable wouldn't compile.

Comment: that's also linked to the famous https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/12/01/when-is-an-identifier-not-an-identifier-attack-of-the-mongolian-vowel-separator/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Java supports Unicode characters, one or more of the letters in one of the "numbers" variable is unicode letter from different alphabet, you can check this by copy-pasting both of those names and trying to do this:

```
System.out.println("numbеr".equals("number"));
```

They seem same to the naked eye, but they are not, your IDE will show false in the console as the evaluation result. Try it yourself.

EDIT:

The letter 'e' is different, outputs of casting it to int are 101 and 1077, if you do google search for "unicode 1077" the following link is one of the many the search engine will throw at you:

http://www.codetable.net/decimal/1077

As you can see it says it's Cyrillic lowercase letter 'e'.

Comment: where to find those letters ?

Comment: Why should the IDE output anything? Shouldn't the program itself do it?